# How to applyBindings and keep input values with Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm building a HTML/KnockoutJS application. My webserver returns a form with input fields with information. When I new up my model and do an `ko.applyBindings`, naturally the input values are overwritten by the model.

Is there a way to do an `ko.applyBindings` in which the model is **automatically** loaded with the data of the input fields?

---

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/p7ygq5y2/1/

HTML:

```
Title: <input data-bind="textInput: title" value="MyTitle" placeholder="Nothing here!" /><br/>
Text: <input data-bind="textInput: text" value="MyText" placeholder="Nothing here!" /><br/>
<button id="bind">Bind!</button>
```

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.initFromInput = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    valueAccessor()(element.value);
  }
};

function Model() {
  this.title = ko.observable();
  this.text = ko.observable();
}

document.getElementById('bind').onclick = function() {

  var model = new Model();
  ko.applyBindings(model);

};
```

Comment: Have the server return a model instead?

Comment: I can't rewrite on the server. I'm only allowed to work on client-side magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom binding, that tells Knockout to use the input values as default, like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.initFromInput = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        valueAccessor()(element.value);
    }
};
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kv3zras3/3/

EDIT:

With the new binding, your data-binds should look something like this:

```
<input data-bind="initFromInput: title, value: title" value="MyTitle" placeholder="Nothing here!" />
<input data-bind="initFromInput: text, value:text" value="MyText" placeholder="Nothing here!" />
```

EDIT:

There's an abit nicer way of achieving this, if you make like binding look like this:

```
var origValueInput = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;
ko.bindingHandlers.value.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    if (allBindings.has('initValueFromInput')) {
        valueAccessor()(element.value);
    }
    origValueInput.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

You can write your data-binds like this:

```
<input value="MyTitle" data-bind="initValueFromInput, value: title"/>
<input value="MyText" data-bind="initValueFromInput, value: text"/>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yy51kok5/

Comment: I doesn't seem to work for me. Check https://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/p7ygq5y2/3/

Comment: Check the data-bind in the fiddle I linked, your data-binds should look something like this data-bind="initFromInput: title, value: title", if you want to use the initFromInput binding.

Comment: I switched it to simple 'value' binding, but still not result: https://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/p7ygq5y2/5/

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! I've added another solution you might like a bit more, the data-bind looks prettier there.

Comment: Yep! Looks way better!! No redundancy ==> cleaner code! ;-)

Comment: It works even with `textInput`! I'm leaving it open for others to comment and vote. I usually close a question after a few days.

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up improving the answer from clean_coding. Add the following anonymous method to a script after loading KnockoutJS. It will reroute both `textInput` and `value` handlers.

```
(function () {

    var z = ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init;
    ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        if (allBindings.has('initWithElementValue')) {
            valueAccessor()(element.value);
        }
        z.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    var y = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        if (allBindings.has('initWithElementValue')) {
            valueAccessor()(element.value);
        }
        y.apply(this, arguments);
    };

}())
```

It can be used, by specifying it after the `textInput` or `value` declaration:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: title, initWithElementValue" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Ended up creating a plugin for Knockout. Added it to GitHub as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/KeesCBakker/KnockoutAutomaticFormValueBinding/master/knockout-automatic-form-value-binding-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

1. Include the plugin
2. Set `ko.automaticFormValueBinding = true;`
3. Bind `ko.applyBindings({yourmodel});`

More info at Git: https://github.com/KeesCBakker/KnockoutAutomaticFormValueBinding