# Knockout JS keep original html with html bind

Tags: knockout.js

I have been tasked to replace a bunch of HTML on a page when the user performers certain actions (like search, filter...). The HTML is requested via ajax. I already made it work with Jquery, but now they want it with Knockout JS instead. So I started learning it yesterday, and ended up with this simple code sample.

HTML

```
<div data-bind="html: header"><h1>Initial header</h1></div>

<button id="submitButton">Update page</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/myKnockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS:

```
(function ($, ko) {
  var viewModel = {
    header: ko.observable() // Initially blank
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

  $('body').on('click', '#submitButton', updatePage)

  function updatePage() {
    viewModel.header("<h1>New header</h1>");
  }

})(jQuery, ko);
```

But when I load it, KO removes the original h1 (because off the binding). I would like the header to be the same until it is updated via the button.

I have found this example, that gets the original value:
[How to applyBindings and keep input values with Knockout JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696141/how-to-applybindings-and-keep-input-values-with-knockout-js)
But it only works on "value" bind, and I can't get it to work on "html" bind.

Comment: What you're saying is that the value of `header` is not really "Initially blank" but rather "Initial header". Why not `header: ko.observable('Initial header')`, then?

Comment: Because in the real senario, it's not a static text. It's generated from the server.
<h1>@Model.Header</h1>

And to be more precise, it's even more complicated, because it's not just a "Header" property. It's a combination of multiple serverside properties and html elements.

I just kept it simple here.

Comment: There's no reason haim770's suggestion won't work. Just update the observable once the real data arrives from the server with the new values. The whole concept behind observables and data binding is that the DOM automatically updates to reflect changes do your data so make use of that and change your data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom binding that would essentially be a wrapper around the `html` binding which saves the initial content. You would need to provide an observable to hold the old value.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.savehtml = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    const [currentValue, oldValue] = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    oldValue(element.innerHTML); // save the old content

    // forward the arguments to html init in the expected format
    const args = [...arguments];
    args.splice(1, 1, () => currentValue); // valueAccessor
    return ko.bindingHandlers.html.init.apply(this, args);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    const [currentValue] = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    const args = [...arguments];
    args.splice(1, 1, () => currentValue); // valueAccessor
    return ko.bindingHandlers.html.update.apply(this, args);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
<div data-bind="savehtml: [header, oldHeader]">
  <h1>Initial header</h1>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/69em73r5/)

---

To delay the binding until there's an actual change, this could be tweaked. Create a subscription and set the html as it's updated. That way the initial content is untouched until your new value is set.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.deferredhtml = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    const html = valueAccessor();
    if (ko.isSubscribable(html)) {
        html.subscribe(h => ko.utils.setHtml(element, h))
          .disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved(element);
    }
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
  }
};
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/69em73r5/6/)

Comment: I was looking into custom bindings, but I was way off compared to what you wrote here :)

I checked your demo, and it changes the header to "hello world" on load. The goal is that the header must not change until I make a call to viewModel.header("<h1>New Header</h1>")

Comment: Ah I see, so don't modify until a new value for the header is set. Essentially delaying the binding until there's a change.